# Making Table of Contents entries boldface

Tags: table-of-contents, bold, tocloft

So far, I want to create this kind of Table of Contents for my research proposal:
[image]

Sadly, all I have is this one:
[image]

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
    \setlength{\parindent}{2.30em}
    
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{xfrac}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\usepackage[top=1.8in, bottom=1.25in, left=1.75in, right=1.25in, headheight=1.25in]{geometry}

% Fonts
\usepackage{sectsty} 
    \allsectionsfont{\normalsize}
    \chapterfont{\normalsize \centering \bfseries}

% References
\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber]{biblatex} % for APA 7
\addbibresource{References.bib}

%Pagination
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \pagestyle{fancyplain}% <- use fancyplain instead fancy
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

% Caption
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{format=hang, font=normalsize, labelfont=bf, justification=justified, labelsep=period}

% Graphics
\usepackage{graphicx}
    \graphicspath{{./Figure/}}
    \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.jpeg,.jpg,.png}

% Spacing
\usepackage{setspace} % control linespacing
    \setstretch{1.5}
    
\makeatletter 
    \patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\vspace*{50\p@}}{}{}{}         % Removes space above \chapter head
    \patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{\vspace*{50\p@}}{}{}{}        % Removes space above \chapter* head

% Renew commands
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase{Table of Contents}}

\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalfont\bfseries}% titles in bold
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\normalfont\bfseries}% page numbers in bold
\renewcommand{\cftdotsep}{1}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\bfseries\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}}% dot leaders in bold

\begin{document}
    \pagenumbering{roman}

    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Title Page}
    
    \addtocounter{page}{1}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Table of Contents}
    \tableofcontents
    \newpage

\end{document}
```

How do I pull off the boldface chapters/sections with dots specifically for everything before Chapter 1 of my research paper? Help is very much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Edited title of question because me forgot to edit

Comment: You have already set the chapter entry in boldface, but you add a section entry by ` \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Table of Contents}` , try ` \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Table of Contents}`. They should be in boldface.

Comment: But by doing so, the dots will be gone @Tom. I wanted to have boldface entries with dots.

Comment: The dots are still there in my end, is there any settings you didn't show in the example?